# JDKはJREを兼ねていますか？

Tags: java

JDKはJREを兼ねていますか？

Java環境が必要なソフトを動かすのにJREが必要ですが、JDKをインストールするだけではだめなんですか？
JDKはJava実行環境をもっているものとおもっていたのですが、あるフリーソフトを開こうとしたところ、JREがないというエラーがでました。

Comment: アプリがJREがどこに置かれていることを想定しているのか（環境変数やシステム設定に素直に従っているのか、そうではないのか）によって結果が変わります。なんというアプリがどのようなメッセージを出してエラーになったのかを書くとより具体的なアドバイスが可能になると思います。

Answer (score 0):

JDKはJREを包含します。

Java8以前のものであるなら、Sun/Oracleのインストーラでインストールしていることを前提にして、(Windows)なら特定のレジストリやインストールパスパターンを見たりしている可能性もあるのかなと思います。
原因が分からないのであれば、要求されているものをその通りインストールするのが無難ではないでしょうか。

---

[Java Platform Standard Edition 8ドキュメント](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/):

> JDK 8はJRE 8のスーパー・セットで、JRE 8のすべての機能に加えて、アプレットやアプリケーションの開発に必要なコンパイラおよびデバッガなどのツールを備えています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]